# UITextField rightView image and button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm having 2 problems with `UITextView`. I have a `UIViewController` that has 5 `UITextField`. `UITextField1` and `UITextField2` are always visible and cannot be hidden by the user. If the user taps on a button, it adds (`isHidden` property is set to `false`) up to 3 more `UITextFields`.

Each of those `UITextFields` should show as a `.rightView` a custom `UILabel` that shows the left characters. In addition to that, the 3 additional `UITextFields` should also add as a `.rightView` a `UIButton` that when it's tapped it should animate `textField.isHidden = true` so that it makes the illusion that it deletes the `UITextField`.

**The problem**

The delete `UIButton` of the right view, doesn't work (ie doesnt hide the corresponding `UITextField` and I'm not sure why. Right now when you tap the delete `UIButton` it sort of hides the button itself which is odd

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.count + string.count - range.length

    let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 25))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    label.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Light, size: 14)

    if textField === thirdChoiceTextField || textField === forthChoiceTextField || textField === fifthChoiceTextField {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: rightView.frame.width - 30, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "icon_cancel_dark"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideTextField(textField:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        rightView.addSubview(button)
    }

    rightView.addSubview(label)
    textField.rightView = rightView
    textField.rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    label.textAlignment = .center

    if newLength <= 35 {
        label.text =  String(50 - newLength)
        label.textColor = .lightGray
    }
    else {
        label.text =  String(50 - newLength)
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    return newLength < 50
}


@objc func hideTextField(textField: UITextField) {
    if !textField.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            textField.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `func hideTextField(textField: UITextField)` method, the parameter should not be a `UITextField`, it should be a `UIButton` itself as below,

```
@objc func hideTextField(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ...
}
```

and the below line

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideTextField(textField:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Will change to

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideTextField(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And now you can apply the animation as below,

```
@objc func hideTextField(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let  field = sender.superview?.superview as? UITextField, !field.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            field.isHidden = true
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Excellent! That's what I was trying to do! Thank you

Comment: @Dani Glad it helped!